# jquery ajax progress bar

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I am trying to setup a ajax progress bar for my site. Sometimes multiple ajax calls are chained together Here is my code

```
var xhrs = [];


function ajaxCall(){
    xhr = $.ajax({
        ...other ajax code...
        success: function(data){
            anotherAjaxCall(data);
        }
    });
    xhr.onreadystatechange = reportStatus;
    xhrs.push(xhr);
}

function anotherAjaxCall(data){
   xhr = $.ajax({
       ...other ajax code...
   });
   xhr.onreadystatechange = reportStatus;
   xhrs.push(xhr);
}
...lots more functions that make ajax calls....

 function reportStatus(){
    var overallPercent = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < xhrs.length; i++){
        overallPercent += (xhrs[i].readyState * 20);
    }
    var percent = overallPercent / xhrs.length;
    alert(percent + " = " + overallPercent + " / " + xhrs.length);
    //update progress bar
    updateProgressPercentage(percent);
}
```

From the alert in the reportStatus function all happens is the first ajax call gets to readyState of 4 and it calls the second function that doesn't run the ajax call inside of it. Does anyone have any idea why the second function runs but that ajax call inside doesn't. Thanks in advance.

Tim

Comment: I assume `anotherAjaxCall` is not actually defined as `xhr = $.ajax({});`?

Comment: yea, i should have make that more clear sorry.

Comment: for what purpose do you want to use ajax? and how do you plan to get  the response continuously and use it?

Comment: it is an intranet page that a user can add time entries to different jobs. The page can search for jobs through ajax and then the user can add time and log entries through ajax.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I found out the answer. To do this i need to user jQuery 1.3.2. Version 1.4.2 must change the xhr somehow, version 1.5.1 completely changes it. Thanks for the responses everyone.

Comment: To anyone reading this nowadays: **DO NOT** use an ancient version of jQuery just because of this!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have the syntax wrong for the AJAX call with no parameters. Try changing

```
xhr = $.ajax({});
```

to

```
xhr = $.ajax();
```

The documentation says this is how you're supposed to call the function with no parameters: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: There are parameters in the ajax calls i just removed them to reduce the code on this page.

Answer (score 0):

They changed it to use what they call jqXHR objects.  These expose readyState, but do not allow for arbitrary setting of other values.  See [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details.  What you can try, however, is using the "xhrFields" option that was added in 1.5.1 to add your onreadystatechange callback.